# How do I create a date field in sqlite and define the date format for it?

Tags: android, string, sqlite, datetime, android-studio

I want to store a date field into my database. In order to do that, I think I might need a format to store inside the database.

**How can I set the format for that date field? And in the java code part, the variable I should used, is it a Integer? Or just a String?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks a previous search on SQLite TimeStrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use DATE field as varChar i.e in String format.

**ex :** add this to your table for date **COLUMN_varDisplayDate + " Text ,"**

use this method to format date as per your requirements,

```
public static String getDateFormat(String date) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String convertedDate = "";
        try {
            Date parseDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            convertedDate = fmtOut.format(parseDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertedDate;
    }
```

Comment: So the database can only store the format of (yyyy-MM-dd)? is the hyphen necessary?

Comment: And the date field should be storing string (because with hyphens)? Or just integer?

Comment: taking date in string will be easy than to in integer so this is effective way otherwise it will be complex.

Comment: so after it stores a string, and it's a date type, it can already be compared by statement?

Comment: yes, you can do that and later if you want to change format you can do that.

Comment: Thanq...@Johnny Cheuk.

Comment: How can I change the format from "yyyy-MM-dd' to "d MMM yyyy" while I have the string in the format "yyyy-MM-dd' ?

Comment: it is not allowed format as it has d MMM yyyy space.

Comment: d MMM yyyy is a format that shows something like this: "23 Dec 2015"
What I need is totally 2 date format, one is for storing and one is for showing in the textview

Answer (score 1):

[Allowed Date-Time format in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

> How can I set the format for that date field?

Use SimpleDateFormat to format your exiting Date Object or Date String object as above specified format.

> variable I should used, is it a Integer? Or just a String?

String

Answer (score 0):

You can store date in form of number of **seconds(since Jan 1 , 1970)**.
It can be stored in Integer format. for getting date in form of seconds you can use `getTimeInMillis()` function of `Calendar` class which gives you time in milliseconds and divide it by 1000.

For displaying it in user readable format you can just format that date depending upon which database you are using.
for Sqlite you can use `strftime` function to retrieve date in desired format.

http://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/sqlite-strftime.php